# Security between native iOS app and server

Tags: ios, security, authentication, client, server

I'm developing a native iOS app and have a backend PHP server communicated with HTTPS.

What I have now is that I can login with username/password login, facebook or google login.
The server will generate a token and send it to the user. The user will use this for every call to the server.

But:
- The server "guy" have chosen to send a new token every time a make a call. I think this is bad design for several reasons.
- Should it expire? If so, how can I seamless for the user experience renew the token? If not, isnt this vulnerable?

Is above a good design? I would also like to know what you guys are using as your security design?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For Securing Token in Device ,Using SSKeyChain instead of NSUserDefaults . There is no need to generate a new Token for every call . For every Login/ Signup  , Use can Generate a Token .

Comment: Isn't there a security problem with no expiration?

Comment: No as such , But still if you want . Renew the Token and in application if token doesn't match send back to login screen .

Comment: "If token doesnt match..." Would you renew the token with the existing token?

Comment: @Nam : That can also be a solution , but its better to throw user to login screen

Comment: OK, I would really like to prioritize the user experience - that they dont have to login all the time. I can store the username/password in the SSKeyChain and use refresh tokens on FaceBook and Google+. But I'm kind a new in all this token based authentication and unsure why renewing token with token isnt the best idea. Do you have an example of a design pattern?

Comment: You can Explore SSKeychain . You will surely get an answer for renewing Token too. Happy Coding .

Comment: Sorry, Explore SSKeychain?

Comment: @Nam : Explore for yourself dude . Its all in Github .

Answer (score 0):

Store the token in the SSKeyChain instead. Use this method to reuse the same token.

```
- (NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString
{
    NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];

    NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
    {
        strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
        [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
    }    
    return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a security problem with no expiration?

Comment: @Nam You can keep an expiry of a week or month rather than sending new tokens every-time. The best way is to store the token in a keychain and recall it every-time the user accesses the application, so the user does not need to log in again. The token should be newly generated only after a logout and then re-login or after a fix expiration period.

Comment: I'm kind a new in all this token based authentication. Do you have an example of a good design pattern for this?

Comment: @Nam Check this post : http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/41-authentication-with-afnetworking

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not that unsecure code wise, but more interested in the architecture / pattern you use, when dealing with login. How would/do you implement your authentication?